# Django migration is not changing database in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-migrations

I have deployed my Djnago app using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have added some data and everything was working fine. Then I have increased **max_length** of one of the CharField in model.py. I have deployed the app again using **'eb deploy'** command. But it did not increase the field length in database. If I try to add subject_id greater than 10, I get this error: **django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(10)**

**Model.py:**

```
class Subject(models.Model):
        #subject_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
        subject_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

**0001_initial.py:**

```
#Generated by Django 3.0.4 on 2021-02-18 18:54
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True
    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0001_initial'),]
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Subject',
            fields=[('subject_id', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)),],),]
```

I have added migration command in .ebextensions/django_build.config file. The 0001_initial.py file inside migration folder shows the changes. But it is not updated in the database(AWS RDS postgresql). I have checked **django_migrations** table in postgresql database. It's showing the last migration happened when I first created the instance.

I need to change subject_id field length of Subject model in existing database. Any help will be appreciated.

**.ebextensions/django_build.config:**

```
container_commands:
  01_create_log_folder:
    command: "mkdir -p log && chown webapp:webapp -R log"

  02_source_env:
    command: "source /etc/profile.d/sh.local"
    leader_only: true  
    
  03_database_migrations:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py makemigrations --noinput && python3 manage.py migrate --noinput && deactivate"
    leader_only: true
```

**django_migrations table:**

```
select * from django_migrations;
 id |       app       |                   name                   |            applied            
----+-----------------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------
 28 | fileupload      | 0001_initial                             | 2021-01-22 11:42:40.726471+00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your revised migration has the same name (`0001_initial`) as the one you've already applied, it is not being executed. You need to either:

- Create a new migration (`0002_new_migration`) that alters the fields you created in the first one

**OR**

- First rollback the migration you have and then apply the revised one

To rollback the migration you have, you'll need to SSH into the ELB instance:

```
Login via SSH - check your AWS console for specific instructions
```

Then run the following to reset the `accounts` migrations

```
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
source /opt/python/current/env
cd /opt/python/current/app
./manage.py migrate accounts zero
```

When you deploy next, you'll be starting the `accounts` model from scratch and your new migration will run.

This is no different than when you reverse migrations locally using `manage.py` and `migrate`, except you're doing it on your remote instance.